# Smarty fetch метод выводит шаблон на страницу

Tags: php, smarty

Пробовал ниже представленные варианты, при любом из них метод `fetch` отображает шаблон на странице.

Вариант 1:

```
$content = $smarty->fetch('products.tpl');
$smarty->assign('content', $content);
$smarty->display('main.tpl');
```

Вариант 2:

```
$smarty->assign('content', $smarty->fetch('products.tpl'));
$smarty->display('main.tpl');
```

PHP: 5.4.20

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось банально и просто. В шаблоне есть {foreach}, а я ему передавал объекты. Преобразовал в массив и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
$smarty->display();
```

Компилирует и отображает шаблон

```
$smarty->fetch();
```

Компилирует и возвращает шаблон

Comment: Именно. Мне нужно вернуть шаблон с помощью fetch(), но он как раз таки этого делать не хочет, он его отображает. Вот что я имел ввиду :)

Comment: @gpwm а если закомментить строку с display() ?

Comment: Комментирование не помогло

Comment: @gpwm да ну, не может быть. Более чем уверен, что проблема не в этом коде.